# HID terminal for windows

Tags: c#, c++, c, stm32, wdk

I have develop a firmware for my STM32 device. In this device i have define a CUSTOM HID interface for send/receive string via this interface. My USB interface description vector:

```
/**** Descriptor of CUSTOM HID interface ****/
0x09, /*bLength: Interface Descriptor size*/
0x04, /*bDescriptorType: Interface descriptor type*/
0x00, /*bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface*/
0x00, /*bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting*/
0x02, /*bNumEndpoints*/
0x03, /*bInterfaceClass: CUSTOM_HID*/
0x00, /*bInterfaceSubClass : 1=BOOT, 0=no boot*/
0x00, /*nInterfaceProtocol : 0=none, 1=keyboard, 2=mouse*/
0x00, /*iInterface: Index of string descriptor*/

/**** Descriptor of CUSTOM_HID ****/
0x09, /*bLength: CUSTOM_HID Descriptor size*/
0x21, /*bDescriptorType: CUSTOM_HID*/
0x11, /*bCUSTOM_HIDUSTOM_HID: CUSTOM_HID Class Spec release number*/
0x01,
0x00, /*bCountryCode: Hardware target country*/
0x01, /*bNumDescriptors: Number of CUSTOM_HID class descriptors to follow*/
0x22, /*bDescriptorType*/
0x33,/*wItemLength: Total length of Report descriptor*/
0x00,

/**** Descriptor of Custom HID endpoints ****/
0x07, /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
0x05, /* bDescriptorType: */
0x04, /*bEndpointAddress: Endpoint Address (OUT)*/
0x03, /* bmAttributes: Interrupt endpoint */
0x40, /* wMaxPacketSize (64 bytes) */
0x00,
0x0A, /* bInterval: Polling Interval (10 ms) */

0x07, /*bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size*/
0x05, /*bDescriptorType:*/
0x81, /*bEndpointAddress: Endpoint Address (IN)*/
0x03, /*bmAttributes: Interrupt endpoint*/
0x40, /*wMaxPacketSize (64 bytes) */
0x00,
0x0A, /*bInterval: Polling Interval (10 ms)*/
```

I have tested my device for send/receive string on Linux and it's work nice (a simple echo string to hidraw device).
Now i'm trying to develop a simple program in Windows (try with v7x64 and v10x64). I have tested a lot of library:

- (Python) [pywinusb](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb)
- (C#) [HIDSharp](https://github.com/jcoenraadts/hid-sharp)
- (C++) [hidapi project](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi)
- (Utility) [YAT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/y-a-terminal/)

In my tests, i send a message like this:

```
0x00 (Report ID)
0x41 (Report payload) (A)
...
```

But in all my test i see that not all messages are send to device. For example, i need to send 10 or more times the same string before device receive the message.
How i can improve the communication between Windows and device?

Comment: If it works in Linux and not in windows the issue is usually the terminating character of the string.  What character(s) are you using to terminate the messages?  Are you sending binary data. If so you need to add a length of the message before sending the data.

Comment: In windows, strings are terminated with carriage return and NL. In Linux its just NL.

Comment: I use NL in each environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debug i have found the problem.

On STM32 library it's possible define the HID buffer size

```
#define USBD_CUSTOMHID_OUTREPORT_BUF_SIZE ...
```

Unix systems omit the control of this buffer size, but Windows not! 
In my case, i have defined a buffer of 1024 byte (in a USB FS version). When i tried to send message, windows send a chunks of 64 bytes and it can't receive any bytes from USB until buffer wasn't full.

After changed the buffer size with the right value, 64 bytes, communication works well on Windows too.